# How to file_get_contents for URL that loads content via javascript?

Tags: curl, file-get-contents

I'm loading the contents of certain external pages to monitor mentions on particular topics. I use file_get_contents for this, and this works fine, most of the time.

However, this fails for a particular URL. If I switch to cURL, I am able to see what is loaded, and notice that the site uses javascript to, it seems, load remote content. Is there a way to work around this, and, presumably, only get the contents after the remote content has loaded?

Here's an example URL of which I can not capture the contents with either file_get_contents nor cURL:

https://www.diariodocentrodomundo.com.br/militares-escolhidos-por-heleno-ainda-dirigem-sala-no-planalto-sobre-os-povos-indigenas

I *suspect*, but have not tried, that it might be possible to get this to work with something like PhantomJS. But, I prefer a PHP-based solution, and PhantomJS seems to have been abandoned some 5 years ago.